# Change ok cancel option of bootbox to yes & no

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootbox

Can anyone tell me how I should change the `ok` & `cancel` option of the Bootbox to `yes` & `no`.

```js
function deletelaw(id) {
  bootbox.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?', function(result) {
    if (result) {
      $("#deletelaw_" + id).hide();
      $(".law1_" + id).prop("checked", false);
      var splits = $("#laws_assigned1").val().split(",");

      var finalSplit = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        if (id != splits[i]) {
          finalSplit.push(splits[i]);
        }
      }
      $("#laws_assigned1").val(finalSplit.join());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: RTM? http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-confirm-examples

Comment: See their documentation: http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-confirm-dialog. Specifically the `button` parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass **[`buttons`](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-option-buttons)** object to change the buttons label and style this way :

```
bootbox.confirm({
  message: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
  buttons: {
    confirm: {
      label: 'Yes',
      className: 'btn-class-here'
    },
    cancel: {
      label: 'No',
      className: 'btn-class-here'
    }
  },
  callback: function (result) {
    if (result) {
      $("#deletelaw_" + id).hide();
      $(".law1_" + id).prop("checked",false);
      var splits = $("#laws_assigned1").val().split(",");

      var finalSplit = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        if (id != splits[i]) {
          finalSplit.push(splits[i]);
        }
      }
      $("#laws_assigned1").val(finalSplit.join());
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: Where did you get this from? It's not under **Confirm** in the docs, maybe it's under **Prompt**?

Comment: Oh I found it, you can find it by clicking on the link **Options described below. Thanks anyway!**

Comment: Sorry @jewishspiderweb I didn't seen your comment till now..

Comment: No problem. Great Answer!